# Assigning Counts from Unstructed Text

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm looking for a more efficient method to assign animal counts to their respective columns.

have:

```
  data.frame(
    size = c(50,50,50),
    type = c('50 monkeys', '25 monkeys | 25 apes', '30 monkeys | 10 monkeys | 10 monkeys')
    )
```

want:

```
   data.frame(
            size = c(50,50,50),
            monkeys = c(50, 25, 50), 
            apes = c(0, 25, 0)
)
```

current method:

```
  dat_ %>% 
    mutate(monkeys = unlist(lapply(str_extract_all(type,paste0('[0-9]+',’monkeys’)), function(x) sum(parse_number(x)))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `separate_rows` to split the `|` delimited data in different rows, `separate` to split count and name of animal in different columns and `pivot_wider`  to get data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  separate_rows(type, sep = '\\s*\\|\\s*') %>%
  separate(type, c('count', 'type'), sep = '\\s+', convert = TRUE) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = count, 
              values_fn = sum, values_fill = 0) %>%
  select(-row)

#   size monkeys  apes
#  <dbl>   <int> <int>
#1    50      50     0
#2    50      25    25
#3    50      50     0
```

Comment: this is about 5 times faster than my previous code. thank you!